# Nutch/Solr Indexing Sentences - Parser plugin or Indexing plugin?

Tags: solr, nutch, opennlp

Trying to index full sentences as their own field. If I do the sentence splitting in Nutch, using something like OpenNLP or LingPipe, where do I plug in the sentence detecting code? In the parsing stage or in the indexing stage?

Answer (score 0):

Both the places need some modifications.

The nutch parsers chop off formatting from the crawled content. So the newlines are gone when the content is stored in the nutch segments. You need to modify that part.

By default, nutch (its solr which does this) will consider words and not sentences for indexing. So you have to peek there too.

Comment: I managed to modify BasicIndexingFilter.java to use OpenNLP, however, I just added tokens in between sentences so I can use a SpanQuery later. This might work fine, but I want to try to index the actual sentences as fields -or- documents themselves... This is what I'm now confused about. Do I index each sentence as documents themselves with fields such as 'sentence','id','url','title'... -OR- Can I continue to index each web page as the document and keep the default Nutch fields but add a field named 'sentences' with MULTIPLE ENTRIES? Is that even possible? I'm confused conceptually.

Comment: given the vagueness, i think your latter suggestion is better suited. take a look at the Schema.xml in your solr conf directory, in there you will have a field definitions, add a new field and mark it as multiValued ... this allows you to attach multiple sentences (as an array) for the crawled page.